# Inverted axis in pose mode

Tags: animation, bones, pose-mode

I have this mesh with their bones... the first (upper, called Target) bone is selected in pose mode. The bone next (down) the "Target" has IK.

[image]

as you can see the location and rotation are with cero's.

But when need to move or rotate trying to use the location and/or rotation transform... the axis are inverted...

[image]

If I modify the axis Z in location, the bone moves across the Y axis... why is that?

**NOTE**

That bone is not connected with others bones, to be a target bone, with the IK. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the rotation of the object/bone, maybe? (CTRL+A>Rotation)

Comment: No, already did it, but not work.